# printing an string in cross manner using c program

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'am trying to write a program for converting the given string in cross manner(i.e Diagonal from left-right and from right-left). If the string length is even it returns a message else arrange it in a cross form.

The code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{   

    char str[50];
    char str2[50][50];
    int lenstr;
    int i,j;
    char temp;

    printf("Enter the string :\n");
    scanf("%s",str);
    lenstr = strlen(str);
    if(lenstr %2 == 0)
    {
        printf("The string length must be an odd length");

    }

    else
    {
        j = 0;
        temp = 0;

        for(i = 0;i == lenstr;i++)
        {
              str2[i][j] = str[i];
              j = j + 1;
        }

        for(i = lenstr; i==0 ;i--)
        {
              j = lenstr;
              str2[i][j] =  str[temp];
              temp = temp + 1;
              j = j - 1;

        }

        for(i = 0;i<lenstr;i++)
        {

             for(j = 0;j<lenstr;j++)
             {

                 printf("%c",str2[i][j]);
             }

             printf("\n");

          }

     }

     return 0;

}
```

The output to the program must be for example: geeks

```
g       g
  e   e
    e 
  k   k 
s       s
```

But the output obtained consists of different shapes(like heart,smiley face etc...). Explain the concept behind to correct it and if can please explain when using pointers for the same program. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why is the upper part of the figure is large than the lower part of the figure?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow how does it look now? ;-)

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh  I think that it should be done without the second array.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes, that would be the elegant way of doing it. I was just trying to point out to the mistake in OP's code. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you need to change the `for` loop condition checking expressions, like `i == lenstr` and later `i==0`. They are not entering the loop, essentially.

Instead, you can replace the whole block

```
for(i = 0;i == lenstr;i++)
  {
      str2[i][j] = str[i];
      j = j + 1;
  }

  for(i = lenstr; i==0 ;i--)
  {
      j = lenstr;
      str2[i][j] =  str[temp];
      temp = temp + 1;
      j = j - 1;

  }
```

in your code by

```
for(i = 0;i<lenstr;i++)
    for(j = 0;j<lenstr;j++)
      str2[i][j] = ' ';      //fill 2D array with space

  for(i = 0;i < lenstr;i++)
  {
      str2[i][i] = str[i];               //set the character
      str2[i][lenstr- i -1] = str[i];    //reverse position
  }
```

and get the desired output.

See it <kbd>[LIVE](http://ideone.com/CmkQrI)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic to store diagonal string seems to be wrong. In the first loop you store left-right diagonal and your index goes from 0 to length-1 and your column starts from 0; increment it by 1. Its same for right-left diagonal, only difference being column starts from length-1 and ends at 0. Hence you need to initialize temp = lenstr -1;

```
temp = lenstr -1;
        for(i = 0;i <lenstr;i++)
      {
          str2[i][j] = str[i];
          j = j + 1;
      }

      for(i = 0;i <lenstr;i++)
      {
          str2[i][temp] =  str[i];
          temp = temp - 1;    
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that str2 is not getting initialized. The first two for loops should be something like

```
for(i = 0;i < lenstr;i++)
```

and

```
for(i = lenstr; i>=0 ;i--)
```

Comment: Hey thanks. I just added an condition to check if i == j if it is store each character value to that array element, and i got output to print in left-right alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my five cents. The program allows to enter words with an odd or even number of letters.

Enjoy!:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N   25

int main(void)
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        char s[N];

        printf( "Enter a string less than %zu characters (Enter-exit): ", N );

        if ( !fgets( s, N, stdin ) || s[0] == '\n' ) break;

        size_t n = strlen( s );
        if ( s[n-1] == '\n' ) s[--n] = '\0';

        printf( "\n" );

        for ( size_t i = 1, j = n; i <= n; i++, j-- )
        {
            char c = s[i-1];
            if ( i < j ) printf( "%*c%*c\n", i, c, j - i, c );
            else if ( j < i ) printf( "%*c%*c\n", j, c, i - j, c );
            else printf( "%*c\n", i, c );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter

```
Stackoverflow
hello
```

then the program output will be

```
Enter a string less than 25 characters (Enter-exit): Stackoverflow

S           S
 t         t
  a       a
   c     c
    k   k
     o o
      v
     e e
    r   r
   f     f
  l       l
 o         o
w           w
Enter a string less than 25 characters (Enter-exit): hello

h   h
 e e
  l
 l l
o   o
Enter a string less than 25 characters (Enter-exit):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class CrossCharacter {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = in.next();
        int len = str.length();
        char[][] ch_matrix = new char[len][len];
        len--;
        for(int i=0;i<=len;i++)
            ch_matrix[i][i] = ch_matrix[i][len-i] = str.charAt(i);
        for(int i=0;i<=len;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<=len;j++)
                System.out.print(ch_matrix[i][j]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! While this code might answer the questions it would benefit from from an explanation of how it solves the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
# include<stdio.h>
void main() {
  char n[100],temp;
  int i = 0, j;
  scanf("%s", &n);
  m = strlen(n);
  for(i = 0; i <= m - 1;)
    temp[i];
  i++;
  for(j = 0; j < m - 1; j++)
  {
    if(i == j + 1 || j == m - 1 - i + 1)
      printf("%c",temp);
    else
      printf(" "):
  }
  printf("\n");
  getch();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! While this code might answer the questions it would benefit from from an explanation of how it solves the question. Use the [edit] button to improve your answer.